# Getting all the members of a group in Active Directory via C#

Tags: active-directory

Hey guys, I tried searching online and mostly on here but most answers don't satisfy.
I want to get all the users that have a certain group in their memberOf attribute, but can't seem to LDAP query them properly. The string I'm using for the filter is "(&(objectClass=user)(memberOf=cn=,ou=,dc=, dc=))" - which gets no results what so ever. If I remove the 'memberof' clause it finds all the users.

My first conclusion is that multi-valued attributes such as memberof cannot be simply queried like so. What is an alternative solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the users are direct (non-nested) members of the group you're filtering?  The filter `(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(memberOf=CN=GroupName,OU=A,DC=domain,DC=edu))` works as expected here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing it [one of these ways](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=.net+get+ad+users+group+members)? [This one looks particularly useful.](http://dunnry.com/blog/2007/08/01/GettingActiveDirectoryGroupMembershipInNET35.aspx), if you don't have 3.5, then [the following](http://dunnry.com/blog/CategoryView,category,Groups.aspx) may be of more help?